# In react on first time data is getting fetched, when user move to chat with one another user, state value is not getting change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am new in react and node, trying to build chat application, On clicking user, for one-one chat, I am fetching records from database , and backend node.js, I had also used socket.io .

Chat.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import io from "socket.io-client"
import { Container,Row,Col,Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import {fetchUserById,fetchRoom,fetchChats} from '../services/services'
export default function Chat() {
    const history=useHistory()
    
    const [username,senderId] = 
[localStorage.getItem("username"),localStorage.getItem("senderId")];
    const receiverId=window.location.pathname.substr(6)

    localStorage.setItem("receiverId",receiverId)

    const socketRef = useRef();

    const [ oldChat, setOldChat ] = useState([]);
    const [receiver, setReceiver] = useState("");

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchUserById(receiverId).then(res=> setReceiver(res.data.message[0].username))
    })
    const receiverUser=receiver

    const setLogout=()=>{
        localStorage.setItem("loggedin", false);
        history.push('/signin');
    }
    const [ state, setState ] = useState({ senderId:senderId ,message: "", username: username,receiverId:receiverId,roomId:"",receiverUser:receiverUser})
    const roomId1=senderId.substr(12);
    const roomId2=receiverId.substr(12);
    useEffect(
        () => {
            fetchRoom(roomId1,roomId2).then(res=> {
                localStorage.setItem("roomId",res.data.message);
                setState({senderId,message:"",username,receiverId,roomId:res.data.message,receiverUser})
            })
            const roomId=localStorage.getItem("roomId")
            fetchChats(roomId,senderId,receiverId).then(res=>{
                if(res.data.status===200){
                    setOldChat([res.data.message])
                    // console.log(oldChat)
                } else{
                    console.log(res.data.message)
                }
            })
            
            socketRef.current = io.connect("http://localhost:4000" ,{transports: ['polling']})
            socketRef.current.on("message", ({senderId,username, message,receiverId,roomId,receiverUser }) => {
                setOldChat([ ...oldChat, { senderId,username, message,receiverId,roomId,receiverUser } ])
            })
            return () => socketRef.current.disconnect()
        },[oldChat]
    )
    const onTextChange = (e) => {
        setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
    const onMessageSubmit = (e) => {
        const { senderId, message,receiverId,roomId,receiverUser } = state
        
        if(message===""){
            e.preventDefault()
            alert("please enter message")
        }else{
            // console.log("state====>>>",state);
            socketRef.current.emit("message", {
                senderId,username,message,receiverId,roomId, receiverUser
            })
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    }
    
    const renderChat = () => {
        return oldChat.map((e)=>{
            return e.map((ee)=>{
                if(ee.senderId===senderId){
                    return <div key={ee._id}><b>{username}</b>:{ee.message}</div>
                }
                else{
                    return <div key={ee._id}><b>{receiverUser}</b>:{ee.message}</div>
                }
            })
        })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Container fluid>
                <Row className="p-2">
                    <Col>
                        <h1 align="left">Login successful</h1>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={{span:2,offset:4}}>
                        <Button onClick={setLogout} className="btn btn-danger btn-block">Logout</Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className="p-2">
                    <form onSubmit={onMessageSubmit} style={{float:"right",position:"fixed",right:"150px"}}>
                        <h1>Send message</h1>
                        <div>
                            <input type ="text" name="senderId" disabled  value={state.senderId} label="SenderId" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type ="text" name="username" disabled  value={state.username} label="Username" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type ="text" name="roomId" disabled  value={state.roomId} label="RoomId" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type ="text"
                                name="message"
                                onChange={(e) => onTextChange(e)}
                                value={state.message}
                                id="outlined-multiline-static"
                                variant="outlined"
                                label="Message"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button>Send Message</button>
                    </form>
                    <div>
            <h1 style={{position:"fixed",background:"#fff", marginTop:"0px"}}>Chat log history</h1>enter code here
                        <p style={{marginTop:"35px"}}> {username} is talking to {receiverUser}</p>
                        <div style={{float:"left"}}>
                        {renderChat()}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I checked data is getting from back-end node server, issue with react.js.
On first time it will fetch the chat records but when I move to chat with other user it will give with last user chat messages, I have to refresh the page, to get all chats messages of current users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use another useEffect hook  for fetchChat  API

```
useEffect(()=>{
               fetchUserById(receiverId).then(res=> 
               setReceiver(res.data.message[0].username))
             },[receiverId])

             

 useEffect(() => {
                fetchChats(roomId,senderId,receiverId).then(res=>{
                 if(res.data.status===200){
                    setOldChat([res.data.message])
                    // console.log(oldChat)
                 } else{
                    console.log(res.data.message)
                 }
                })
  
             }, [roomId, senderId, receiverId]);

  

  

  useEffect( () => {    
      socketRef.current = io.connect("http://localhost:4000" ,{transports: 
      ['polling']})
      socketRef.current.on("message", ({senderId,username, 
        message,receiverId,roomId,receiverUser }) => {
         setOldChat([ ...oldChat, { senderId,username, 
         message,receiverId,roomId,receiverUser } ])
     })
    return () => socketRef.current.disconnect()
},[oldChat])
```

Comment: I tried but it gives me repeat of whole chat and goes it into infinite loop.

Comment: so in this case, you must call the fetchChat API call  if  roomId or  senderId or  receiverId changes otherwise don't call it only fetch API call when the component first time renders or if there are any changes occur in roomId or  senderId or  receiverId . I update my answer try it

Comment: Yes, Its working, Thank you.
But still for millisecond past user data is displaying, could you please guide me what should I do for that?

Comment: when it occurs when the component is first time rendered or you move to chat with another user?

Comment: Yes, when I move to chat with another user.

Comment: I think it's server response time but not sure  about that . if u have a huge amount of data  u need to add scroll event when you scroll up the old data will show like whatsapp

Comment: hmm, okay, thank you so much, your answer are very helpful.